# How to add subtotal and grand total to Panda Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use the Pandas dataframe to put in three columns to track, which is 'Qty', 'Added Value', and 'Trans. Cost' then have a grand total for all products but subtotal for each product code.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample Data
data = {
    "Terminal": ["LalaLand Fert Term", "", "", ""],
    "Location": ["LaLaLand, OZ  42242", "", "", ""],
    "Product Code": ["AM", "Laha", "Laha", "Laha"],
    "Agvance Blend Ticket Number": ["333338235", "333338257", "333338291", "333338256"],
    "Invoice/ Transfer # (Ticket No) (Vendor ID)": [
        "NAA01745220/123735863",
        "NAA01745220/123735863",
        "NAA01745220/123735863",
        "NAA01745220/123735863",
    ],
    "Qty": [-9.083, -20.51, -5.4, -3.260],
    "Added Value": [600.60, 890.2, 581.72, 203.89],
    "Trans. Cost": [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
}

# Import the sample data into a panda dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create a pivot table with grand total added
pivoted = df.pivot_table(
    index=["Location", "Product Code", "Agvance Blend Ticket Number"],
    values=["Added Value", "Trans. Cost", "Qty"],
    aggfunc={"Added Value": "sum", "Trans. Cost": "sum", "Qty": "sum"},
    margins=True,
    margins_name="Grand Total",
    fill_value="",
).sort_index(ascending=False)

# create two more columns to track
df2 = df.groupby(
    [
        "Location",
        "Product Code",
        "Agvance Blend Ticket Number",
        "Added Value",
        "Trans. Cost",
    ],
    as_index=False,
).agg("sum")

# combine the pivot table and the df2
df = (
    (pd.concat([pivoted, df2]))
    .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
    .fillna("")
    .sort_values(
        ["Location", "Product Code", "Agvance Blend Ticket Number"], ignore_index=True
    )
    .sort_index(ascending=False)
    .drop_duplicates(
        subset=["Location", "Product Code", "Agvance Blend Ticket Number"], keep="last"
    )
)

# print out the result
print(df)
```

I've been able to "bludgeon" the code into producing the output below.

```
  Terminal             Location Product Code Agvance Blend Ticket Number Invoice/ Transfer # (Ticket No) (Vendor ID)     Qty  Added Value  Trans. Cost
8           LaLaLand, OZ  42242           AM                   333338235                                              -9.083       600.60          0.0
7                                       Laha                   333338291                                              -5.400       581.72          0.0
6                                       Laha                   333338257                                             -20.510       890.20          0.0
5                                       Laha                   333338256                                              -3.260       203.89          0.0
0                                                                                                                     -9.083       600.60          0.0
```

However, I cannot control the columns that I do not want showing up as I'm only interested in 'Location', 'Product Code', 'Agvance Blend Ticket Number', 'Added Value', and 'Qty'.

There are unwanted columns showing up and I suspect that's due to the dataframe, even though I thought the pivoted variable would prevent that when I concat the df2 and pivoted together.

Furthermore, I cannot figure out how to create a subtotal for each product. I have tried to use sidetable, but it only works on single column, not multi-index.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from where you left off, here is one way to do it:

````py
# Select desired rows and columns
df = df.loc[
    8:5,
    ["Location", "Product Code", "Agvance Blend Ticket Number", "Added Value", "Qty"],
].reset_index(drop=True)

# Save for later
grand_total_added_value, grand_total_qty = df["Added Value"].sum(), df["Qty"].sum()

# Add sub totals
dfs = []
for product in df["Product Code"].unique():
    tmp = df.copy()
    tmp = tmp.loc[df["Product Code"] == product, :]
    tmp.loc[tmp.shape[0], ["Product Code", "Added Value", "Qty"]] = [
        f"subtotal/{product}",
        tmp["Added Value"].sum(),
        tmp["Qty"].sum(),
    ]
    dfs.append(tmp.fillna(""))

# Add sub dataframes back together and add grand total
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df.loc[df.shape[0], ["Product Code", "Added Value", "Qty"]] = [
    "grand total",
    grand_total_added_value,
    grand_total_qty,
]
df = df.fillna("")
Then:
```python
              Location   Product Code Agvance Blend Ticket Number  \
0  LaLaLand, OZ  42242             AM                   333338235   
1                         subtotal/AM
2                                Laha                   333338291   
3                                Laha                   333338257   
4                       subtotal/Laha                   333338256   
5                         grand total

   Added Value     Qty  
0       600.60  -9.083  
1       600.60  -9.083  
2       581.72  -5.400  
3       890.20 -20.510  
4      1675.81 -29.170  
5      2276.41 -38.253
````